# Symfony2 sending emails in command

Tags: php, symfony, console, twig

I am trying to send e-mails with a service I made in a command. After some changes I made with the security I am having some trouble with it. Every time I run the command, I get the error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException]                                                
The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

I isolated where the error happens, and it`s when I try to render the template of the e-mail. I tried using the templating instantiated with the service, and also passing a templating from the command with

```
$this->getContainer()->get('templating')
```

But still them both give me the same error.

As an additional info, it`s not just one command, but every command that sends e-mail ir having this error.

The function I was using is:

```
public function createMessage($subject, $to, $template, array $atributes, array $from = array(), $returnPath = 'dev@domain.br', $replyTo = 'no-reply@domain.com.br', $templating = null)
{
    if (count($from) == 0) {
        $from = array('no-reply@domain.com.br' => 'Contact');
    }

    if ($templating == null) {
        $tpl = $this->templating->render($template, $atributes);
    } else {
        $tpl = $templating->render($template, $atributes);
    }

    $this->message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->setReturnPath($returnPath)
            ->setReplyTo($replyTo)
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setBody($tpl);

    return $this;
}
```

The error happens when I try to populate $tpl.

I also tried this way:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Você foi bloqueado no sistema')
        ->setFrom('contato@mysite.com.br')
        ->setTo($usuario->getEmail())
        ->setCharset('UTF-8')
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody($this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render('MyBundle:Email:template.twig'));
    $this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

My security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USUARIO]
        ROLE_USUARIO:

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity: { class: MyNamespace\UserBundle\Entity\Usuario }

    encoders:
        MyNamespace\UserBundle\Entity\Usuario: plaintext

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN, parameter: _become_him }
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /login

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/_wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/_profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

      - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

      - { path: ^/adm, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USUARIO }
```

The template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        {% block title '' %}
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width: 680px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #575756; font-size: 16px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 70px;">
                <img src="/img/email/logo.png" style="width: 160px;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background-color: #649cb0; line-height: 7px;">
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0 70px 20px 70px;">
                {% block content '' %}
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="background-color: #649cb0;">
            <td style="padding: 0 70px;">
                <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;">
                            <a target="_blank">
                                <img src="/img/email/acessar.png"  title="Acessar o sistema" alt="Acessar o sistema" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

And the template that uses the above:
    {% extends 'NC8DigitalCRMBundle:Email:layout.html.twig' %}

```
{% block title %}Report{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h3 style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;">Hello,</h3>

{% if qtdNaoDistribuidas > 0 %}
    <h4>Problems found.</h4>
{% else %}
    <h4>Everything is ok.</h4>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my email service:

```
mybundle.email:
    class: MyNameSpace\MyBundle\Services\SendEmail
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@templating", "@mailer", "@service_container" ]
```

Comment: You are using the command, you then don't have nor a request, nor a security context (because you don't have any server request).

The problem may sit where you made changes about the security. But what changes did you make?

Comment: I just added my security.yml @YoannCh . Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your template please @PedroHCan?

Comment: I added the parent tempalte and the template that is called. @YoannCh . Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm i can't really see from where this error comes. Need to investigate more on it.

Comment: may you add the service definition?